# Разбить все часы суток на интервалы по 10 миинут

Tags: mysql, конвертирование-даты

MYSQL
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть сутки
начинаются с 2023-06-21 00:00:00
заканчиваются 2023-06-21 23:59:59

Как можно получить список такого вида
2023-06-21 00:00:00
2023-06-21 00:10:00
2023-06-21 00:20:00
2023-06-21 00:30:00
///

Comment: прибавлять по 10 минут к предыдущему значению

Answer (score 1):

Если версия MySQL позволяет, то получить можно с использованием [рекурсивного CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series), примерно так:

```
WITH RECURSIVE data (dt) AS (
    SELECT '2023-06-21 00:00:00'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
    FROM data
    WHERE dt < '2023-06-22'
)
SELECT * 
FROM data;
```

Comment: Нет к сожалению,была СТЕ нельзя юзать,это 5-я версия...